# Which electronic shifter to choose?

Tags: derailleur, shimano-di2

After a good old fashioned crash because of jumping rear gears I think I am ready to make the move to an electronic shifter/derailleur.

Currently I have a 1x10 setup with internal routing in the frame and drop bars (and drop bar style brake/gear levers) with hydraulic brakes.

I don't want to throw money so will try to find something second hand.  What options are good for a 10 speed rear electronic derailleur and a drop bar style brake/gear lever that will support hydralic brakes?

I mostly ride gravel trails and a little bit of road

Thanks!

Comment: I would investigate the cause of the "jumping gears" rather than "switching to electronic". For example, the case of jumping not attributable to worn components were because I forgot to enable the clutch of the derailleur (in the two cases that would be the same with or without electronic shifting). Also, 1x10/hydraulic seems a strange combination to me (I'm aware of 2x10 hydraulic GRX400 or 1x10 mechanical - Advent X), but I'm not aware of the all products on the market.

Comment: Agree with @Renaud here.  Chances are the skipping has nothing to do with the fact that your current shifter/derailleur combo is mechanical, and instead something else: worn chain, worn cassette, misaligned derailleur hanger, or some combination of all three.  If, for example, the hanger is bent, putting a new derailleur (electronic or mechanical) on it will not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only 10 speed electronic shifter's i'm aware of are Ultegra St-6770, however these are designed for cable operated brakes.
They could probably be paired with a cable pulled hydraulic calliper such as the TRP HY/RD.

Overall i think this would be an expensive and not very advisable conversion to attempt.

Comment: the shifters can be any model, the derailleurs determine the number of speeds with Di2

Comment: Why is it relevant to find a 10-sp shifter? Unless I'm wrong, the derailleur will also need to be replaced, and the only electronic ones are 11-sp (GRX800) and 12-sp (SRAM), so that will require a new cassette and a new chain anyway (and a new chainring if SRAM).

Comment: I (perhaps mistakenly) assumed there would be a 10sp derailleur to match the 6770 shifter.  If there is no such thing then the idea becomes even more expensive and even less advisable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone and after some more investigation  it seems like there are not any good and affordable 1x10 + hydraulic setups available.

The most affordable option would be SRAM Rival eTap shifters and derailleur and then a new chain and cassette.

I will start saving now!